# Hide `(declare)` forms in lisp mode

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

This is actually two questions:

1. Does anybody know an emacs feature that can hide (and maybe indicates that it has done so) selected forms in lisp code ? I've written some performance oriented common lisp and the key functions do contain lots of `(declare (type ...))` forms that clutter the code.
2. If not, does anybody have suggestions on where to be inspired / steal something that would enable me to write it myself ?

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function that finds the start and end positions of the text you want to make invisible. Then use `(put-text-property START END 'invisible t)` to make the text invisible.

For a quick-and-dirty example, use `(search-forward "(declare (type " nil t)`. `(match-beginning 0)` is the start position of that sexp, so `(goto-char (match-beginning 0))`, then do `(forward-sexp 1)` to get to its end position. Then use `put-text-property` as above, to hide the text from the start of the `declare` sexp until its end. Do that in a loop, to hide all such sexps.

To be more careful, you would use a regexp that allows variable whitespace (including newlines) in the sexp, etc. But just the above should get you started.

(To make invisible text visible again, just use `(put-text-property START END 'invisible nil)`.)